# MySQL Getting results for a specific user

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have the following query which works as expected.

```
SELECT T.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM ( SELECT e.guid, 
              e.name,
              (SELECT COUNT(ev.event_vote_id) 
               FROM event_vote ev 
               WHERE ev.event_uid = s.guid) AS votes
       FROM event e
    ) as T
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

It returns the guid, name, vote count and rank of **all** events.

However I want to make it specific to a certain user by linking the **user_event** table using something like the following:

```
JOIN user_event ON t.guid = ue.event_uid
WHERE ue.user_uid = 'abc123'
```

However i'm unsure on where to put this or if this.

---

I have the following query as a start but it returns exactly the opposite to expected i.e. every event not belonging to the user.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM user_event ue
JOIN ( SELECT e.guid,
              e.name,
              e.ownerId,
              e.thumbnailSrc,
              @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank,
              ( SELECT COUNT(ev.event_vote_id) 
                FROM event_vote ev 
                WHERE ev.event_uid = e.guid) AS votes
       FROM event e, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
     ) AS t 
   ON t.guid = ue.event_uid
WHERE ue.user_uid = 'abc123'
ORDER BY rank ASC
```

**expected results**

list of all of the events:

```
guid | name | votes | rank

def    test2     2      1           (user1)
abc    test1     1      2           (user2)
ghi    test3     0      3           (user1)
jkl    test4     0      4           (user3)
```

**what the query should return for user 1 (user1 guid being abc123)**

```
guid | name | votes | rank

def    test2     2      1           
ghi    test3     0      3
```

Comment: so you want rank all events from one user? or see how those specifct events rank among all the events?? Please include some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's forget about rank for a moment, if you want only event from one specific user you do:

```
SELECT e.*, ue.*, ( ... ) as votes
FROM event e
JOIN user_event ue
  ON e.guid = ue.event_uid
WHERE ue.user_uid = 'abc123'
```

And over that result you can do ranking.

```
SELECT T.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM ( ... previous query ... ) as T
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

**EDIT:**

to filter for a single user you need create another subquery.

1. calculate votes
2. calculate ranks
3. filter user

So query become:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT  T.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
       FROM ( SELECT e.*, ue.*, ( ... ) as votes
              FROM event e
              JOIN user_event ue
              ON e.guid = ue.event_uid ) as T
       CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
       ORDER BY votes DESC
     ) as ranked_result
WHERE ranked_result.user_uid = 'abc123'
```

Comment: Actually sorry I think you misinterpreted me, I wish to return the overall Rank. Question has been updated.

Comment: However, my original query seems to work, thank you anyway.

Comment: That is why you always should include sample data and expected output. Otherwise is a guessing game. Anyway dont know how you query work if the rank is calculate inside the subquery :/

Comment: You were correct, the query is broken, however it does work occasionally. Any ideas how to return the overall rank?

Comment: I told you you need do the group by inside of the subquery, and the ranking outside. As I show you in my answer. What is your current query and what is the problem? Can you prepare a sample on sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: I add another version, maybe that solve your problem